# MySQL's utf_general_ci in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, unicode

Is there an easy way to replicate the behavior of MySQL's `utf_general_ci` collation in C#?

In particular, given a Unicode string, I want to generate a(n ASCII?) string that can then be trivially sorted or compared, as `utf_general_ci` would.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net), which shows how to *strip* accents from strings, which looks like a similar but not quite equivalent function, e.g., it doesn't decompose `ß` into `ss`.

For my purposes, that *may* end up being good enough, but if there's a way to replicate its behavior completely I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SortKey class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.sortkey.aspx) and its KeyData property.

For given collation (CultureInfo in .NET terms) and a string, you can get a naturally sortable byte array using MyCultureInfo.CompareInfo.GetSortKey(mystring).KeyData

I do not think the collating keys for .NET and for MySQL will necessarily match, however both are using the same technique based on [Unicode Collation algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)